# Proof that the set of integrable real-valued functions is a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

From *Folland's Real Analaysis: Modern Techniques and Applications:*

> **Proposition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a fixed measure space. The set of
>   integrable real-valued functions on $X$ is a real vector space.
>
> **Proof:** This follows from the fact that $|af+bg|\leq |a||f| +|b||g|$.

I do not see how this proves that the set of integrable real-valued functions is a real vector space. From what I remember, we need to show two conditions:

**(i)** If $f,g \in L^{1}$ then $f+g \in L^{1}$

**(ii)** If $f \in L^{1}$, then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\alpha f \in L^{1}$.

I cannot see how Folland's proof satisfies these conditions. Can someone help explain?

Comment: If $af+bg \in L^1$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then we can take $a=b=1$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}, b=0$ to obtain (i) and (ii). The former inequality shows that $af+bg \in L^1$ because it can be bounded with the elements that belong to $L^1$.

Comment: Recall the definition when the function belongs to $L^1$: $\|f \|_{L^1} = \int |f|dx<\infty$.

Comment: @hcl14 Thanks, I understand now. But how can we be sure that $f$ and $g$ will satisfy this inequality a priori? Is this a property of integrable real-valued functions? Keep in mind that at this point in the book Folland has not introduced a norm on the set of real-valued integrable functions.

Comment: Check the beginning of the proof here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)

Comment: Subadditivity $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$ is always true for absolute value, so we can take it pointwise: $a=\alpha f(x), b = \beta g(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$..

Comment: Yes I see. In the same line of thought, this follows from the fact that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions, i.e. $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, and $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$, and the inequality obviously holds on the real line.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, we do need some previous knowledge: that $f,g$ measurable implies $af+bg$ is measurable.